# View How much to download and how much time left

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Is there any option to get how much data downloaded and how much time left
 When using firebase realtime database

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            };
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no progress or status notifications for Realtime Database listeners.